# Execute dynamic number of ajax request sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

Have the following scenario :

I have to display the graphs for a given interval (startDate,endDate)

Because the interval might be quite big , the data is retrieved per day so I need
to  do multiple ajax calls sequentially and to append the data to the graph(highcharts)

**Example interval is n days ==>**

```
ajax request day 1 

when is (done) ready ajax request day 2

when is (done) ready ajax request day 3

....

ajax request day n
```

I read about deferred and promises BUT I found difficult to with dynamic number of days and the requirement to get the responses sequentially

Thanks

Comment: But large amount of data may crash the browser;

Comment: One way can be using the **success** block of each ajax request to fire another. Just to ensure the sequence. But, this should strictly be done if number of ajax requests are finite and max upto (2 or 3 requests).

Comment: Well ... better that crashing the server :) The idea is that it runs on what is called admin server with very very little amount of memory (256 MB). The browser has more for sure.

Comment: @Abhi is not limited :(

Comment: Create a recursive function using setTimeout

Answer (score 3):

If you're able to store the list of dates in an array, you can use something like this:

```
var items = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Alphalpha'];

//replaceable with any function that returns a promise
function asyncFunction(item) { 
  return $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/html',
    type: 'POST',
    data : item
  })
  .then(function(data){
    $('body').append('<div>Got the response from '+item+'</div>');
    //stuff stuff stuff
  });
}

function sequence(arr, callback) {
  var i=0;

  var request = function(item) {

    return callback(item).then(function(){

      if (i < arr.length-1)
            return request(arr[++i]);

    });
  }

  return request(arr[i]);
}

sequence(items, asyncFunction).then(function(){
    $('body').append('<div>Done with all!</div>');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ojy9jnx/2/

Basically, `sequence` takes an `Array` of items and runs a function on all of them (in this case `asyncFunctions`, which can be replaced with any function), a function that returns a promise.

This is very basic implementation, you'll notice, for example, it has no error handling. Libraries like async.js have an exhaustive list of tools that accomplish tasks like this, but who knows, maybe this will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you already figured it out, but a good way to tackle your problem would be using a combination of jQuery.Deferred and recursion. Check out this sample code and see if it helps clarify things:

```js
function getData(dayLimit) {
  var allDone = $.Deferred();

  var getDataForDay = function(day) {
    doAsyncThing(day).done(function() {
      if (day < dayLimit) {
        getDataForDay(day + 1);
      } else {
        allDone.resolve();
      }
    }).fail(function(){
      /*
        Reject the deferred if one of your operations fails.
        Useful if you're binding "fail" or "always" callbacks
        to the promise returned by getData.
      */
      allDone.reject();
    });
  };

  getDataForDay(1); //start with first day

  return allDone.promise();
}
```

Let me know if you need more clarification, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

What about recursively calling. Create a parameterized function and pass the day to the function like,

function getDetails(day) {

```
//  ajax call
//  In the callbacks call the getDetails function by updating the date
```

}

Comment: You should add more details, also, you are not creating a loop

Comment: If we are going to call the function(Recursively) in the callbacks by updating the date then why we need loops?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express myself well, and I had been under the impression the OP wanted to make a request every 24 hours.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Jquery in your Application try pushing all the ajax to an array

ex 
[ajax,ajax,...]

and then user

```
$.when([ajax,ajax,...]).then(function(){
 console.log(arguments);// you will get the success messages in arguments array 
})
```

Comment: This is when all of them are finished ....BUT they are all executed in parallel , I would need a sequential execution. So when day 1 is retrived get day to ...etc